# C# Dynamic link library functions

Tags: c#, wpf, dll

I've been trying to make DLL which can share functions to .exe files, but Im getting errors :(

This is the function I want to share to my executable (This code is located in DLL file, inside the class1)

```
public static void WriteToFile(string filename, string text)
{
    File.WriteAllText(filename, text);
}
```

Okay, no errors so far, this is what I do:
1. Build the solution + the DLL itself.
2. Add this DLL to the reference of my executable.
3. I include it in the namespaces of the executable, so I am able to use the content of the dll.

Im trying to use the function in the dll, and trigger it within a button.
It says the whole function doesn't exist :/

I've tried moving the DLL function to outside of the class, then it gives this error

```
Error: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
```

Okay, I tried switching the void to delegate, and class, more errors appear.

I think im missing something little but can't just find the correct solution anywhere. Hopefully someone in the other side of the window can answer with a proper solution :)

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you're doing wrong exactly, but this should work if your project has a reference to `ClassLibrary1` and if `Class1` is marked `public`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    ClassLibrary1.Class1.WriteToFile("file.txt", "hi there!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you get, tells you are writing code where the compiler do expect some type definition, and not code. Write your code inside a method, or maybe inside the Main() entry point.